# Deep copy a NavigableMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, deep-copy, concurrenthashmap

I have a `NavigableMap` with the following format:

```
NavigableMap <Long, String> mymap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap <Long, String> ();
//.......some operations

NavigableMap <Long, String> newmap;
//clone mymap into newmap;
```

How can I deep-copy/clone contents from `mymap` into `newmap`? Java 8 should be fine to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Long` and `String` are immutable; there's no need for a deep copy. Just do `new TreeMap<>(mymap)`.

Comment: Or `new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(mymap)`, to get the same implementation class…